# Salesforce LWR Experience Cloud Deployment Error - "add a default owner for guest-user created records."

Tags: deployment, change-set, lwr, deployment-error, experience-bundle

I am trying to deploy a experience LWR experience site, i added the network component to the change set and added all its dependencies. then i uploaded it to a sandbox and the site was successfully deployed.

but when the client admin tries to deploy using the same way to production, we get the following error :
add a default owner for guest-user created records. the default owner must be an active user in the org and not a guest user

Can someone please help me with why this error is coming in the production org.

Answer (score 0):

I think the user selected as default owner for records created by guest user is not present/active in production org. To fix this-

From the source sandbox you are tying to deploy, open the Workspace->Administration-> preferences and See record ownership. There will be a user selected as default owner. Make sure this user is existing and active in your production.
Alternatively you can change the owner to a active user who is existing in source and target production org both.
Hope this works!